# Require 2 decimal places after the point in PHP?

Tags: php, decimal, currency

I'm working with currencies so for example -

5 is OK as it is interpreted as 5.00. But 5.005 is not as it has too many digits after the point.

**How can I restrict the amount of digits and show an error if there's too many?**

Thanks

Comment: disregard the possible duplicate please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = '5.005'; // declare as string to avoid floating point errors
$parts = explode('.', $x);
if (strlen($parts[1]) > 2) {
   die("Too many digits");
}
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens with `$x = '5';`? You may need to fix that but +1 since this is the best answer so far (involved with input rather than output).

Comment: you'd end up with just `$parts[0]` defined, $parts[1] would be undefined but have a strlen of 0. changing to `if (isset($parts[1] && strlen(...)) ...` should fix that up.

Answer (score 2):

number_format will correct it for you, but if you want to error when too much precision is provided, you will need to test it.

```
$x = 12.345;
if ($x != number_format($x, 2)) {
    // error!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the number like this:

```
 $num = 50695.3043;
 $num = number_format( $num, 2, '.' );
 echo $num;
```

This will result in:

```
 50695.30
```

Note that this rounds. So 1.566 would round to 1.57.

Comment: See my comment to diEcho, this dictates the output rather than restricts the input.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$formatted = sprintf("%01.2f", $price);
```

But there are many other functions / solutions you could use.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will capture a number of things from a user-entered string:

- too many decimal points, such as `1.2.3`.
- more than two digits in second section (if there), such as `1.234`.
- any non-numerics in first or second section, such as `123.4a` or `1a3.45`.
- both first and second section empty, such as `.`.

---

```
$x = '12.34';
$parts = explode('.', $x);
$nm0a = preg_match ('/^[0-9]*$/', $parts[0]);
$nm0b = preg_match ('/^[0-9]+$/', $parts[0]);
$nm1a = preg_match ('/^[0-9]*$/', $parts[1]);
$nm1b = preg_match ('/^[0-9]+$/', $parts[1]);

if (count ($parts) > 2)           { die ("Too many decimal points"); }
if ($nm0a == 0)                   { die ("Non-numeric first part"); }
if ($nm1a == 0)                   { die ("Non-numeric second part"); }
if (($nm0b == 0) && ($nm1b == 0)) { die ("Both parts empty"); }
if (strlen ($parts[1]) > 2)       { die ("Too many digits after decimal point"); }

die ("Okay");  # Only here to provide output.
```